# How to filter the files with a certain path in os.walk function?

Tags: python, bash, macos

I am trying to find and print a list of files. 
In other words, I want the list of files to be displayed if the file extension matches (in this case `*.wav` files) and one string from their path. If both are true it should be displayed.
The file path appears in somewhere in the middle of the path string.

```
import glob
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Volumes/FreeSys/Repos/zz_Test_Files/_Ordnerstruktur_190205"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".wav"):
             print(os.path.join(root,file))
```

This code currently finds `.wav` files according to the path which is set under the `os.walk` function.

In theory, I need just to spend an `and` to the `if` clause, which lets only files to be displayed, where `2_Recorded_Files` is in the path. If that string is not in the file path, then that file should be ignored.
Since I am starting my journey learning Python I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you know where in the path `2_Recorded_Files` appears? If so, you can use `glob` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach would be to break down the `root` into a list of all folders that make up the path, and to check if `2_Recorded_Files` is in this list. Paths can be tricky, however, as they can behave differently on different operating systems. We can split the path in `root` using `os.sep`, which contains the separator used in the operating system you are executing the code on.

```
import glob
import os

target_folder = "2_Recorded_Files"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Volumes/FreeSys/Repos/zz_Test_Files/_Ordnerstruktur_190205"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".wav") and target_folder in root.split(os.sep):
             print(os.path.join(root,file))
```